# Ionic - toggle button

Tags: cordova, button, ionic-framework, togglebutton

Currently in my project, I am able to change colour when my button is `active`. However, I have 2 buttons. Does anyone know how to change the active mode of these 2 button alternately? When 1 is active, another will be inactive immediately, or vice versa.

html

```
<ion-view title="Single Projector Room" id="page9">

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item" ng-click="goBack()">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"> Back</i> 
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content padding="true" style="background: url(img/EDD79InSMCeYeMOSchjm_remote.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;" class="has-header">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><br><br><br><br></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><h4 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Single Projector Control</h4></div>
  <div class="col col-30 text-center"><h4 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Screen Control</h4></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-large icon-right ion-power" ng-class="{'active': buttonActive}" ng-click="toggleButton()">On</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-dark button-large icon-right ion-arrow-up-c">Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-large icon-right ion-android-cancel" "button button-large icon-right ion-power" ng-class="{'active': buttonActive}" ng-click="toggleButton()">Off</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-dark button-large icon-right ion-arrow-down-c">Down</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><br><br></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><h4 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Mic Control</h4></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-balanced button-large icon-right ion-power">On</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-assertive button-large icon-right ion-android-cancel">Off</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('singleProjectorRoomCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {

$scope.buttonActive = false;

    $scope.toggleButton = function() {
      $scope.buttonActive = !$scope.buttonActive;

    };

$scope.goBack = function() {
window.history.back();
}
}])
```

Comment: is this for ionic 1?

Comment: Yes, it is for ionic 1

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a workaround of what you want to achieve:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.onactive = true;
    myCtrl.offactive = false;

  myCtrl.changeColorIcons = function(button) {

      if (button === 'on') {
        myCtrl.onactive = true;
        myCtrl.offactive = false;
      } else if ( button === 'off') {
        myCtrl.onactive = false;
        myCtrl.offactive = true;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
.button.active, .button:active{ background:yellow !important;}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/js/ionic.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/js/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.23/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
    
    <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl as myCtrl">
<ion-view title="Single Projector Room" id="page9">

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item" ng-click="goBack()">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"> Back</i> 
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content padding="true" style="background: url(img/EDD79InSMCeYeMOSchjm_remote.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;" class="has-header">

  


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-large icon-right ion-power"ng-class="{active: myCtrl.onactive}" ng-click="myCtrl.changeColorIcons('on')">On</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center">
      <button class="button button-large icon-right ion-android-cancel" ng-class="{active: myCtrl.offactive}" ng-click="myCtrl.changeColorIcons('off')">Off</button>
    </div>
   
  </div>

 

  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Which? I only see your post.

Comment: the buttons are toggling with yellow color.. what you want to achieve?